# Can I export a map to SVG using the Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I want to use the Google Maps API to create a custom map with labels removed an colors changed (so far no problem), then export that map to SVG. If that's not possible, an export to PNG would be okay. The goal is to move the resulting map into a canvas element for further processing with fabric.js. Is this possible and if so how? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Google Maps Static Maps API?

http://goo.gl/5KTX0

It supports styled maps and PNG format.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that's the best solution.